# Why is my jQuery click function not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a search page that posts back to itself.  I finally got a sample  [page working here](http://majorgeek.azurewebsites.net/ShowHideSearch.html).  I also  [built a fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tgr131/cf0z0yrn/3/). But I don't understand why it  works.  When the user initially hits the page, it should only show the search form. When a search is submitted, it should hide the form,  show  results, and a button  for a new search.  I'm using jQuery.  Here's my  code:

```
//Code Block 1
// Show search form if there is no querystring
//Hide search form, show  results if querystring
$(document).ready(function() {
if(document.location.search.length) {
    $("#newsearch").show(1000);
    $("#results").show(1000);
    $("#search").hide(300);
} else {
    $("#search").show();
}
});

//code block 2
//if new search clicked, show form, hide  results

     $("#newsearch").click(function() {
    $("#newsearch").hide(1000);
    $("#results").hide(1000);
    $("#search").show(300);

});
```

When code block 1 and 2 are loaded in the head, block 2 never fires.  When I pull 2 out and put it at the end  of the page,  it works.

I am trying to learn, so I have 2 questions.  (1) Why didn't it work when it was one block, and (2) Any suggestions for doing it better?

Thank you.

D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$("#newsearch").click(function() {` is being run **before** the `#newsearch` element exists.

Therefore the click event is attached to nothing.

It works in the first block because it's in a `$(document).ready`, which runs code inside only after everything has finished loading.

Comment: Slaps forehead!  Thanks  so much.  I am new at this, and it was important  to me to understand why I got it working for the future.